# Programmatically add another instance of XYZ directive from within the XYZ directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I have a directive that contains a text box and a button to add another instance of the same directive onto the page.

The ngModel I'm setting in the main controller is the model that I want all instances to use with each new directive creating a new property on the model object prior to the new instance being added to the page.

Adding the directives programmatically works fine but I just can't seem to get the data-binding working as I expect. Either all the textboxes have the same value or the model is not updated at all.

```
angular.module('app')
.directive('myTextBox', function ($compile) {
return {
    templateUrl: 'directive.tpl.html',
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        myModel: '=ngModel'
    },
    link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {

        var propertyId = 0,
            propertyName = 'TextBox';

        scope.model = attrs.ngModel;
        propertyId = attrs.ngModelPropertyId;
        scope.modelPropName = attrs.ngModelPropertyName + propertyId;

        scope.value = scope.subscription.value;


        scope.add = function(){

            var newTextBox,
                propName = propertyName + (parseInt(propertyId, 10) +1);

            newTextBox = angular.element(document.createElement('my-text-box'));


            Object.defineProperty(scope.myModel, propName, {
                enumerable: true,
                configurable: false,
                writable: true,
                value: ''
            });

            newTextBox.attr('ng-model', 'myModel');
            newTextBox.attr('ng-model-property-name', propertyName);
            newTextBox.attr('ng-model-property-id', propertyId);

            el = $compile(newTextBox)(scope);

            angular.element(document.getElementById('elholder')).append(newTextBox);

            scope.insertHere = el;

        };

  }
};
});
```

Am I misunderstanding how to do it correctly or have I fundamentally misunderstood the correct architectural way to do it.

I've created a Plnkr here http://plnkr.co/edit/PXpzVnJc4gMpbuYaPsVn, any help is appreciated.

Comment: this isn't the angular way to do this at all.  Any time you are using `angular.element`, you are using JQLite (or JQuery, if available) to manipulate the DOM.  You should only manipulate the DOM in ***extreme*** edge cases, and prefer using templates and `ng-repeat` whenever possible.

Comment: in case of this directive, what you are trying to do won't work the way you expect, because the first directive is *isolated* from the page scope, so it can only add the new directive into *it's own* scope, which isn't what you really want.

Comment: Thanks for the help Claies, seems my (lack of) experience is showing through!

What is the "correct" way to be doing this? In order to allow a user to dynamically create an unlimited number of additional text boxes (or in my real-world case, a collection of form elements like text boxes, date picker, time picker etc hence the directive)?

How would you suggest I go about doing this? Thanks.